# homotopy extension property

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Wikipedia defines homotopy extension property (hep) as followed:

Given a pair $(X,A)$, we say that it has hep if given a function $F_0: X \rightarrow Y$ and a homotopy $f_t: A \rightarrow Y$ such that $F_0|_A = f_0$, then there exists a homotopy $F_t: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $F_t|_A = f_t$. It never mentions that $F_0$  is equal to the original $F_0$ though? Is this just unfortunate notation or is it actually equal?

Comment: Of course it should be equal.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course actually equal, or it wouldn’t be much of an *extension* property.

We are given a continuous function ($F_0 \cup f_t$) defined on $A\times [0,1] \cup X \times \{0\} \subseteq X \times [0,1]$ and we want to extend to the whole product.